# Using a base abstract class to combine two similar classes

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I am working on a pull request for a project and was told that it may be a good idea to combine the code of two similar classes into one abstract class that the two other classes would extend from. My issue is I am not on the proper way to do this. Here are the two classes:

```
public class ClassOne<OUT> extends RichInputFormat<OUT, InputSplit> implements NonParallelInput {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassOne.class);

private final String query;
private final ClusterBuilder builder;

private transient Cluster cluster;
private transient Session session;
private transient Result<OUT> resultSet;
private Class<OUT> inputClass;

public ClassOne(String query, ClusterBuilder builder, Class<OUT> inputClass) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(query), "Query cannot be null or empty");
    Preconditions.checkArgument(builder != null, "Builder cannot be null");
    Preconditions.checkArgument(inputClass != null, "InputClass cannot be null");

    this.query = query;
    this.builder = builder;
    this.inputClass = inputClass;
}

@Override
public void configure(Configuration parameters) {
    this.cluster = builder.getCluster();
}

@Override
public BaseStatistics getStatistics(BaseStatistics cachedStatistics) throws IOException {
    return cachedStatistics;
}

/**
 * Opens a Session and executes the query.
 *
 * @param ignored
 * @throws IOException
 */
@Override
public void open(InputSplit ignored) throws IOException {
    this.session = cluster.connect();
    MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session);

    Mapper<OUT> mapper = manager.mapper(inputClass);

    this.resultSet = mapper.map(session.execute(query));
}

@Override
public boolean reachedEnd() throws IOException {
    return resultSet.isExhausted();
}

@Override
public OUT nextRecord(OUT reuse) throws IOException {
    return resultSet.one();
}

@Override
public InputSplit[] createInputSplits(int minNumSplits) throws IOException {
    GenericInputSplit[] split = {new GenericInputSplit(0, 1)};
    return split;
}

@Override
public InputSplitAssigner getInputSplitAssigner(InputSplit[] inputSplits) {
    return new DefaultInputSplitAssigner(inputSplits);
}

/**
 * Closes all resources used.
 */
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error while closing session.", e);
    }

    try {
        if (cluster != null) {
            cluster.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error while closing cluster.", e);
    }
}
}
```

And the second:

```
public class ClassTwo<OUT extends Tuple> extends RichInputFormat<OUT, InputSplit> implements NonParallelInput {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassTwo.class);

private final String query;
private final ClusterBuilder builder;

private transient Cluster cluster;
private transient Session session;
private transient ResultSet resultSet;

public ClassTwo(String query, ClusterBuilder builder) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(query), "Query cannot be null or empty");
    Preconditions.checkArgument(builder != null, "Builder cannot be null");

    this.query = query;
    this.builder = builder;
}

@Override
public void configure(Configuration parameters) {
    this.cluster = builder.getCluster();
}

@Override
public BaseStatistics getStatistics(BaseStatistics cachedStatistics) throws IOException {
    return cachedStatistics;
}

/**
 * Opens a Session and executes the query.
 *
 * @param ignored
 * @throws IOException
 */
@Override
public void open(InputSplit ignored) throws IOException {
    this.session = cluster.connect();
    this.resultSet = session.execute(query);
}

@Override
public boolean reachedEnd() throws IOException {
    return resultSet.isExhausted();
}

@Override
public OUT nextRecord(OUT reuse) throws IOException {
    final Row item = resultSet.one();
    for (int i = 0; i < reuse.getArity(); i++) {
        reuse.setField(item.getObject(i), i);
    }
    return reuse;
}

@Override
public InputSplit[] createInputSplits(int minNumSplits) throws IOException {
    GenericInputSplit[] split = {new GenericInputSplit(0, 1)};
    return split;
}

@Override
public InputSplitAssigner getInputSplitAssigner(InputSplit[] inputSplits) {
    return new DefaultInputSplitAssigner(inputSplits);
}

/**
 * Closes all resources used.
 */
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error while closing session.", e);
    }

    try {
        if (cluster != null) {
            cluster.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error while closing cluster.", e);
    }
}
}
```

The differences are in the Constructor(), open(), and nextRecord() methods and the resultSet variable. Also the class for ClassOne has  and ClassTwo has .
The open and nextRecord methods I assume to just not implement them in the abstract base class and leave that to be done in ClassOne and ClassTwo. But the abstract base class will need to have a constructor and the two classes have different constructors and the base class has to have either  or , which would make either ClassOne or ClassTwo not work depending on which is used. I feel like I am overlooking a simple solution.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What version of Java you are using? If you are using Java 8, create an interface and all the common methods can be implemented in that interface using "default" keyword.

Comment: I am using Java 8, and I tried making it an interface instead, but I can't extend the RichInputFormat class to it, so that doesn't seem to be a viable option.

Comment: If the RichInputFormat<> class you are using is this, https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/io/RichInputFormat.html, then you can implement the interface, https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/io/InputFormat.html instead of RichInputFormat.

Comment: That did resolve that issue. However, the base class has to have a constructor that can initialize the query and builder variables so that the rest of the code compiles properly. But with interfaces the constructor can't have a body so this isn't an option.

Comment: Well, if we are going down this route, you can have an init() method which can be called from inside the constructor. The init() method resides in the interface. Do your common stuffs in that init() method. The added advantage is that your constructor looks a lot more cleaner as well.

Comment: Yea, I got the abstract class to work, so I think that is what I will stick with. But thank you, I will probably still look into this too just for the sake of trying to make the code as clean as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is entirely possible to have an abstract class in Java (and other languages) that contain an empty constructor. As such, a composition of the two classes you provided using an abstract class could look something like this:

```
public abstract class ClassAbstract extends RichInputFormat<OUT, InputSplit> implements NonParallelInput {

    private final String query;
    private final ClusterBuilder builder;
    private transient Cluster cluster;
    private transient Session session;

    public ClassAbstract(String query, ClusterBuilder builder) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(query), "Query cannot be null or empty");
        Preconditions.checkArgument(builder != null, "Builder cannot be null");
        this.query = query;
        this.builder = builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Configuration parameters) {
        this.cluster = builder.getCluster();
    }

    @Override
    public BaseStatistics getStatistics(BaseStatistics cachedStatistics) throws IOException {
        return cachedStatistics;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean reachedEnd() throws IOException {
        return resultSet.isExhausted();
    }

    @Override
    public InputSplit[] createInputSplits(int minNumSplits) throws IOException {
        GenericInputSplit[] split = {new GenericInputSplit(0, 1)};
        return split;
    }

    @Override
    public InputSplitAssigner getInputSplitAssigner(InputSplit[] inputSplits) {
        return new DefaultInputSplitAssigner(inputSplits);
    }

    /**
     * Closes all resources used.
     */
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while closing session.", e);
        }

        try {
            if (cluster != null) {
                cluster.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while closing cluster.", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Your ClassOne constructor could then simply be:

```
    public ClassOne(String query, ClusterBuilder builder, Class<OUT> inputClass) {
        super(query, builder);
        Preconditions.checkArgument(inputClass != null, "InputClass cannot be null");
        this.inputClass = inputClass;
    }
```

And ClassTwo's constructor would become:

```
    public ClassTwo(String query, ClusterBuilder builder) {
        super(query, builder);
    }
```

You can then instantiate your child classes by extending your abstract class, and removing all of the code that already exists in the abstract class.

Comment: But the builder variable wouldn't be initialized. I could call the constructor for ClassAbstract within the constructor for ClassOne (or ClassTwo) and add ClusterBuilder builder to the signature for ClassAbstract, but I don't know if that would be like initializing a new instance of ClassAbstract from within ClassOne and not actually updating the inherited builder variable ClassOne has. If that makes sense at all.

Comment: @Jicaar - Keep in mind that abstract classes by definition cannot be instantiated on their own - they must be extended and instantiated through subclasses. I've edited my original post to reflect a constructor in the abstract class, and then the respective constructors in ClassOne and ClassTwo, using the `super()` call to construct the abstract class.

Comment: Yea I just figured that out myself too, thanks. But I have come across a new issue with ClassOne with the nextRecord method. The one that is created for it by default (using intelliJ's alt+enter add methods option) gives "public object nextRecord(object reuse) throws IOException..." and the return type and the type of the reuse object both have to be OUT. But when I change the type of "reuse" to OUT it says the "Method does not override method from its superclass". Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Just figured it out. Had to include <OUT> at the end of the AbstractClass<OUT> when I extend it.